# Adding IP Based Virtualhost in Apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

I want to host multiple sites in my Linux dedicated server but with different IPs for each site. After some Googling I came to know about virtualhost. I am novice in Linux and Apache. I added the following codes in `WHM`'s
 `Service Configuration »Apache Configuration »Include Editor > post_virtualhost_2.conf`

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
ServerAdmin my@email.com
ServerName myexampledomain.com
ServerAlias www.myexampledomain.com
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/myexampledomain
</VirtualHost>
```

But the site is not opening. Do I need to add the domain in Cpanel AddOn domain section ? Please help me creating virtualhost on my server.
N.B. - I have also added the `DNS` `A` records in my domain panel with the ip. My Apache version is 2.4.23.

Answer (score 0):

To adding a multiple site, you are on a right path by adding Virtual hosts in Apache configuration. But that is more useful when you dont have C panel. As you already have access to Cpanel, you can just add domains to the Add on domains, if server hosting plan supports.

Here is the list of steps you should be doing:

1. Find out server's IP.
2. Update your all domains to point to that server by updating respective Name servers/A records. In most cases, updating Name server is enough for domain to point to particular server. It will take some time to get it updated in DNS.
3. Add all those domains in Cpanel Addon domain list. This will also create a folder in your public_html or document root with same domain name. (Though you can configure folder name and path while creating an add on domain)
4. Refresh the domain and its done.

Comment: But with addon domain feature i cannot assign unique ip to other domains. We need virtualhost then. There i am having problem configuring it.

Comment: @AKPal Do you have multiple hosting servers? You might have multiple domains, but when you talk about multi site hosting, you have one server IP that will be used with multiple domains. Otherwise as 24x7cloudservermanagement suggested, you would be needed WHM

Answer (score 0):

Add all the sites that you want to host on the server from WHM and just change the IP of the each wesite account from "Change IP for multiple site option" in WHM.

Make sure you have registered and active name servers and those name servers are configured on WHM as well as for the websites.

So Simple .. why to play with virtual host and all